Platform indepedent CupertinoSwitch in Flutter
In Flutter I have  showAdaptiveDialog which on most platforms this function will act the same as showDialog, except for iOS and macOS, in which case it will act the same as showCupertinoDialog. Is there any in Flutter which could replace cupertinoswitch to be platform independent?
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_app/theme/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          //dark mode
          Text("Dark Mode"),

          // swith toggle
          CupertinoSwitch(
            value:
                Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).isDarkMode,
            onChanged: (value) =>
                Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .toggleTheme(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


did you mean platform specific widget like widget 1 for IOS widget 2 for android ?

there is adaptive switch available Switch.adaptive (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch/Switch.adaptive.html), which takes CupertinoSwitch for apple platforms and Material switch for others

here is the way to do it
import 'package: flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_app/theme/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          //dark mode
          Text("Dark Mode"),



          // Here is the updated code 
          // swith toggle
         Switch.adaptive(
        value: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).isDarkMode,
        onChanged: (value) =>
            Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).toggleTheme(),
      ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

so basically you just need to change to Switch.adaptive because it automatically uses CupertinoSwitch on iOS and macOS and Switch on other platforms.
